# how to make MJML <mj-text> elements display inline-block

Tags: html, css, mjml

I'm new to [**mjml**](https://mjml.io/api/documentation/) and I'm trying to find out if there is a way to make `<mj-text>` elements to display `inline-block` **without** using `<mj-style>` or inline css.

I have an `<mj-text>` which renders dynamically-generated text  - so I have no way to foresee its width. I would like this container's background to end where the text ends and not fill the entire page's width (like block elements do).

Here is and [example](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/H1F2Q09PQ) of the template I'm trying to render:

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        <mj-text align="left" container-background-color="#c3e16d" color="#60b7f1" font-size="14px">
          <span>Dynamically Generated Text</span>
        </mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

After some searching [I did manage to get it to work](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/B1QQNCqP7) using an `<mj-style>` block - but what I'm trying to figure out if there is a more proper way to do it using the `mjml` api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you did it is perfectly fine. You could also simply use inline styles on the `span` tag, like [this](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/ry48injPQ).

As the `span` tag is made for this type of need and does it well already, we didn't implement anything to replace that in MJML.

Comment: In my case I need to have a button beside a text, I'd appreciate your help

Comment: Just use 2 columns, add your text in the first column and your button in the second column.

Comment: @NicolasGarnier What id you're already in a column? MJML doesn't supported nested columns.

Comment: Indeed, in that case you'll need to use a custom HTML table.